# Windows 10 - Connect to OpenVPN Connect profile via command-line

Tags: command-line, vpn, openvpn

On Linux, I run a simple script that first connects to WiFi and opens a VPN connection to my provider, executed via a keyboard shortcut; however, on Windows 10, I get WiFi connected via `netsh`, but the below only opens the OpenVPN Connect client's GUI [v3.3.1 (2222)] to choose the profile, behaving like `openvpn-gui.exe`, being unable get it to connect automatically:

```
openvpnconnect <full path>\profile.ovpn
```

Is there a way to get the Windows client to open a connection directly through a script, omitting the GUI?

Comment: Looks like I might have resolved this... it seems the command-line option is only available with the OpenVPN Community client. If anyone knows differently please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a confirmation from an OpenVPN Inc. representative in the [OpenVPN Forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=32909&p=101914#p101914).

[OpenVPN Connect client](https://openvpn.net/vpn-client/) by OpenVPN Inc. does not currently provide similar command-line functionality to the [OpenVPN Community client](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/). I.e. fully scripted connectivity w/o user intervention is currently only available with the Community client.

Answer (score 1):

You'd call [`openvpn`](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) [directly](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/running-openvpn-from-a-console-window/) after [installing](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/):

```bsh
openvpn --config "%UserProfile%\path\to\profile.ovpn"
```

---

The normal OpenVPN client is the opensource [Community Client](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) *(the software for which the [man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) applies)*, as OpenVPN Connect was designed for [OpenVPN Access Server](https://openvpn.net/access-server/) [paid product]:

- From the OpenVPN Connect [site](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/):

  - *This is the recommended client program for the OpenVPN Access Server...*
  - *If you have an OpenVPN Access Server, it is recommended to download the OpenVPN Connect client software directly from your own Access Server...*
  - *How do I install the client directly from my Access Server?*
  - *Downloading and Installing: Navigate to the OpenVPN Access Server client web interface*
- Per `.\openvpnconnect.exe help`, it doesn't support the ability to connect to a profile via CLI, however `.\ovpnconnector.exe help` leaves the possibility open: 
   <sup>*(requires verification, as I don't use Connect)*</sup>

  ```
  .\ovpnconnector.exe set-config <path> ; .\ovpnconnector.exe start
  ```

Comment: openvpn.exe is not available with OpenVPN Connect -client https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/

Comment: I'm not using the server, just the client to connect to my VPN provider. There are 2 "normal" clients - OpenVPN Connect from OpenVPN Inc, and the Community client which you linked. And an OpenVPN Inc. representative just confirmed that the functionality I'm looking for, scripted automatic connection, is currently only available with the Community client.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out about the paid product thing. What comes to "normal" client - I take your word for it :-) I've never used it before. At work the employer has paid for the VPN solution, at home I've used my VPN provider's client. Wouldn't even have looked into OpenVPN solution if their Win client provided similar scriptable functionality their Linux client does...

Comment: @Peregrino69 By normal, I mean it's the software intended for uses outside of OpenVPN's paid product services _(this isn't my opinion, the man page speaks for itself)_. The functionality you want is within the Community Client, which should also be able to be used to connect to your employer's OpenVPN service unless I missed something on the OpenVPN Server Access site.

Comment: thanks for your kind input. But think about this from the point of view of the uninitiated. Is the difference or intended audience clearly indicated in OpenVPN website? Are man pages the first resource (or even a common one) you refer to when looking for a solution in Windows world? When you've got a choice of application v3.x and 2.x, which one is in Windows world usually recommended? Don't know about the Access Server, but you seem to have missed the fact that I had the issue with "a VPN connection to my provider" - nothing to do with my employer.

Comment: @Peregrino69 **(#)** The difference is stated clearly on the OpenVPN Connect [site](https://openvpn.net/client-connect-vpn-for-windows/) "_This is the recommended client program for the OpenVPN Access Server..._" **(#)** Man pages are the first resource for _any_ command-line program, regardless of OS, as they inform you of the command parameters _(this is what you get with `/?`||`help`||`-help`)_ **(#)** You're comparing versions of two completely different software applications. **(#)** You stated _employer_ in your next to last comment.

Comment: Which obviously means "this is not a recommended solution to access any other but OpenVPN Access solution". Man is a *NIX application, and neither has nor ever had an equivalent in the MS world. Yes, I stated "my employer pays for VPN" to illustrate why I have not encountered OpenVPN in that context. I don't know whats

Comment: got you so riled up but please accept my excuses if I've in any way insulted or disrespected you. It's entirely unintentional. I resolved my issue a week ago, and this "discussion" is entirely fruitless, so I'm leaving here. Please feel free to take the final word if that's your desire.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I'm unsure where you're getting man pages are a "_*NIX application_" and appears you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what man pages are - the help section of command-line programs showing command parameters _(access man pages on Windows by appending `/?` in cmd, using `get-help`||`man` in PowerShell, or appending `help`||`-help` to non-Windows CLI programs, with the Windows man page site being [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/))_. Facts matter and I'm baffled why you're insisting on arguing over the facts laid out within the answer.

Comment: Dude, even "man pages" is an *NIX world expression... the entire concept was introduced in MS world only 2006 with Powershell, somewhat after even NT-based OS:s. .chm-format was introduced 10 years prior. Before that nothing even remotely similar existed. It's still today unknown to vast majority of Windows users, and is not available with cmd.exe. Like you say, facts matter. As fooling around with MS OS since DOS 5 has left me clearly clueless, I will freely admit that you win, my penis is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions**

**Step 1**. Go to the correct location for x64 systems:

cd "%ProgramFiles%\OpenVPN Connect"
Note: if you have the 32 bits program installed on a 64 bits OS, replace %ProgramFiles% with %ProgramFiles(x86)%.

**Step 2**. Install the system service:

ovpnconnector.exe install

**Step 3.** Specify connection profile to use (optional):

ovpnconnector.exe set-config profile <FULL_PATH_AND_FILENAME_TO_PROFILE.OVPN>
Note: if your OpenVPN Connect installation file was downloaded from Access Server or OpenVPN Cloud and came with a bundled autologin connection profile, then you can skip step 3. It will then simply default to the bundled connection profile. It can be found in the program location with the name "ovpnconnector.ovpn" - that is the bundled connection profile.

**Step 4**. Specify the path to a log file (optional):

ovpnconnector.exe set-config log <FULL_PATH_AND_FILENAME_TO_LOGFILE.LOG>
Note: if you skip step 4, the service will write to the default log file in the program location with the name “ovpnconnector.log”.

**Step 5**. Start the service:

ovpnconnector.exe start
The service will now start the VPN connection and log output to the log file.

Note: you will not receive feedback after starting the service if the connection succeeded or not. You can check the log file or use the ping command to verify that the connection is now up and running.

Important: *OpenVPN Connect client should not be running, otherwise service startup will abort.*

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenVPN Connect v3 on Windows in service daemon mode

Starting from OpenVPN Connect v3.2 the application includes a method to set up an OpenVPN connection as a system service. This allows to have the connection up and running right after system boot even when nobody is logged on

https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/use-openvpn-connect-v3-on-windows-in-service-daemon-mode/